# IIS - custom web server - unable to start debugging on the web server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7

I am trying to debug my web application using IIS custom web server. But I am getting an error "unable to start debugging on the web server. a debugger is already attached". But I checked my processes, don't any processes related to that, tried iisreset and even rebooted my system. Still that error is showing my system.

I am using visual studio 2010, IIS 7, .Net 4.0

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following options:

1. Hit Shift+F5 when in Visual Studio and this will terminate the current debug session. You can then hit F5 and this will start a new debug session.
2. Right Click Web Application -> Degug -> Start new instance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread: [Visual Studio - unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server did not respond in a timely manner](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/visual-studio-unable-to-start-debugging.html) 
And you need execute the `cmd` as Administrator and:

```
> cd \
> cd Windows
> cd system32
> issreset
```

Comment: Don't you mean `iisreset` ?